# Proliant dl585 g5 counts ram then turns off

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, boot

I recently aquired a proliant dl585 g5 server that I wish to use as a home server As I have been working with pcs for a long time the first thing I did after I had made sure it was clean inside and ready to use was to download the latest bios update and attempt to flash the bios.

Unfortunately now there seems to be nothing happening. The machine counts the ram, checks the bios, says it has a valid redundant rom and then turns off.

[screen shot right before it turns off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbCRm.jpg)

I am convinced that its just a software problem as I have no error lights, it does give a double beep when it displays the message about the rom but I think that's just where its testing the rom.

Can someone please advise as to what I need to do to stop it just turning off? so that I can use the thing as a file server please?

Answer (score 0):

You should have checked it before upgrading. Try reflashing the old BIOS maybe?